# manpage interpretation of killall command

Tags: linux

From the manpage of `killall`:

> The killall utility kills processes selected by name, as opposed to
>   the selection by pid as done by kill(1).  By default, it will send a
>   TERM signal to all processes with a real UID identical to the caller
>   of killall that match the name procname.  The super-user is allowed to
>   kill any process.

What is the `caller of killall` here? I am confused because I'm running the `killall` command, so aren't I calling it?

Comment: The manual is talking about default actions, where it signals only processes launched by your user ID (normally this means in your session). It is similar to the processes displayed with `ps` (as opposed to `ps -e` for all processes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the manual, as you said, you are the caller of `killall`; `killall` will kill all processes matching the name you specified *as well as* matching the caller's (your) UID (user ID), a.k.a. only the processes owned by the caller (you). This is so that the caller can't accidentally (or maliciously) kill processes that it doesn't own and therefore doesn't have rights to.

As noted in the last sentence in the manpage quotation, the super-user (UID 0) can always kill any process, even if it isn't owned by the super-user.